# How to implement master detail design pattern in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

I am new to ionic 4 and I wanted to implement a master-detail design pattern using ionic 4. Till now I have tried to implement it using ion-split-pane. But using ion-split-pane on a page where I want to implement a master-detail design pattern, it hides my menu bar that is implemented using ion-menu-toggle. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this: https://www.joshmorony.com/implementing-a-master-detail-pattern-in-ionic-4-with-angular-routing/

Comment: Sorry but this is not solving my problem @Sergey Rudenko

Comment: can you share your code that you tried and detail a bit more what exactly you want to achieve? like specifically you want to prevent menu from hiding?